# My label/text in my div won't show

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have my carousel look like this:

[image]

I couldn't get my labels to display properly.

Here is how I create one of my box :

```
<div class="tl-box-wrapper">
    <div class="tl-box">
        <div class="tl-top"> <i class="fa fa-circle yellow"></i>

        </div>
        <div class="tl-bot"> <i class="fa fa-circle yellow"></i>

        </div>
        <div class="tl-right">Yellow</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I create my label in here:

`<div class="tl-right">Yellow</div>`

I'm not sure why **Yellow** is not showing.

Can someone tell me what I missed? My whole code is in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/mxwjtjxw/).

Comment: Why do you have so many lines in your CSS file?

Comment: Ignore that please, I will clean that later.

Comment: Next time clean it before you ask the question, make it easier on those who try to help you.

Comment: It's just my color declaration, and it way in the bottom, and the rest, they need to be there. I'm sorry for my colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your css with the following:

```
.tl-right {
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;

    // ADD THIS
    font-size:20pt;


}
```

see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mxwjtjxw/1/) i made

Your code at .mp-carousel #mp-carousel-overflow  contains font-size: 0pt which basicly means that your font is invisible.

Comment: So my problem is the color of my text is white, that's why I can't see it. right ?

Comment: @rangerover.js no your font-size was 0, which made your code invisible. color can be ignored see edit.

Comment: @rangerover.js a tip, you can inspect your code with chrome, right mouse inspect element. You can see the element styles on the right side see : https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles

Answer (score 2):

Your text isn't showing because `.mp-carousel #mp-carousel-overflow` is setting your `font-size` to 0. You can add `font-size:14px` to `.tl-right` to fix this.

https://jsfiddle.net/mxwjtjxw/10/

Comment: Your Fiddle is pushing my div the next line.

Comment: I see, instead of setting `.mp-carousel #mp-carousel-overflow` to `font-size:0`  You can add `font-size:14px` to `.tl-right` to avoid this. https://jsfiddle.net/mxwjtjxw/10/